# cant upload file other than image

Tags: file-uploads, ee3

Am using 3.0.4

Creating an filed of type `file` and in allowed file types I've chosen all. The filed is not accepting any file type other than image. Is there any place other than `system/ee/legacy/config/mimes.php` to block or white list file types?

**Edit**

I’ve tried mp4 file of size 1MB and txt, xml, docx of size below 50KB.

Comment: Not delved into EE3 yet but I'd start by looking at the file upload directory to ensure that it's allowing images to be uploaded. https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/files/uploads/form.html

Comment: like the title says, am able to upload images, but not any other files

Comment: Apologies, typo on my part. I meant all files. There's an option in the back end to choose which file types are allowed to be uploaded to a directory. The options are 'Images' and 'All files'. Sounds to me like it's set to images only.